# Opening document set from calendar in Sharepoint 365

Tags: office-365, calendar, document, sharepoint-calendar, document-set

I'm struggling with a task that seems to be rather simple but even after hours of googling, I was not able to find an answer which is why I would like to ask you for help. Also I am very new to Sharepoint so please forgive me for asking an obvious question.

In Sharepoint 365 I've got a library containing several document sets with a few small excel files in each of the sets. There are 4 columns in the library defining each document set: Name, Description, Start Date and End Date. I turned this library into a calendar view and it shows the document sets nicely. However, when I click on a document set from this calendar view, it leads me to a form-like page with only the information from the 4 columns from the library. The excel files are not shown in this view. What I would like to achieve is that after clicking on the document set in the calendar view, the site would directly open the Welcome page of the document set. Is this even possible?

**Edit:** since I don`t think I explained my issue precisely enough here an edit with more detail:

My document library with 2 document sets looks like this:

[image: Document library with document sets]

When I display this library on my site in a customized calendar view, it looks like this:

[image: Calendar view of document library with document sets displayed - this is how I want the calendar to look like]

Now when I click on "Project 1" (or "Project 2"), I get to this page, which is only a summary of columns defining the individual document set:

[image: Page from calendar]

What I would like to achieve is to get from the calendar directly to the Welcome page of Project 1 document set:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions or do I have to rething the structure completely - I find document sets very practical for my purpose and it would be tremendously helpful if I could access them directly from the calendar. This is why I would be very thankful for any hint or advice.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a default view for the Document Set under Document Set setting:

[image]

But **calendar view cannot be set as default view**.  It will not be available in the list of views under document set setting.

You can replace the document library web-part and replace it with the calendar view, but it will not be limited to specific document set. It show all the documents instead of document set specific documents.

There might be a workaround through Query String URL webpart but I won't recommend this.

Comment: Dear SharePointer, thank you very much for your answer, however I think I did not explain my issue precisely enough. I edited the question with screenshots and tried to explain myself clearer - would you mind looking at the question again and suggest any answer? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I correct that you want to show a calendar above the document library (excel files)?

Comment: Hi, there will be different types of files, but I already solved the issue - it was actually quite simple. I did not realize that there is a Name (linked to) column in the libraries.