# Library Items Not Showing Up on Calendar (SP2010)

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, view

I've created a library in SP2010 where the primary content type is a Document Set. **I would like to display the document sets in a calendar view, but when I go to do so nothing shows up**. These document sets are not the built-in Sharepoint Event content types, but they do have start and end date columns, so I would think they could be displayed as a calendar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you create custom document set content type? What is the parent content type for the document set content type?

Here is a similar issue post for your reference:

[Opening document set from calendar in Sharepoint 365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235893/opening-document-set-from-calendar-in-sharepoint-365)

Comment: I created a custom site-level content type (called Event) from the built-in Document Set content type. I then added this site-level content type to a new library and added the Start Date and End Date columns. So the parent is the Event site-level content type I created...and the parent to that is the built-in Document Set content type.